# How to return data from GitHub API in XML?

Tags: github

There is official [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) which returns data in JSON, but is there any way to return the data in XML format?

JSON format example: https://api.github.com/repos/github/github-services/issues

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.  Even when setting the `Accept Header` to xml, the API returns JSON:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+xml" https://api.github.com/repos/github/github-services/issues
```

They parse the `xml` part of the header correctly, but still return JSON as you can see here:

```
$ curl -I -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.full+xml" https://api.github.com/repos/github/github-services/issues
(…)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
(…)
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; param=full; format=xml
(…)
```

The [reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/media/) mentions only JSON.

In their [blog](https://github.com/blog/21-the-api), they write something about xml, but the linked guide is dead.  Setting the API version to `v1` or `v2` in the queries above doesn't help either.

Maybe there's an external service to convert the output to XML, but I haven't found one.